# Selenium xpath gives matches only the visible elements

Tags: java, html, google-chrome, selenium, xpath

Selenium xpath gives matches only the visible elements. The HTML page contains lots of other elements which are not visible but present. When trying out the xpath on chrome console, it displays all the elements including the elements which are not visible. But when using the same xpath in selenium, it returns only elements which are visible at that point in time. Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: Selenium would find you elements which are *present in the DOM*. If an element is invisible, it cannot be interacted with, e.g. you cannot click it or send keys to it.

Comment: There is probably something else going on. Probably wait for all the elements loaded properly. As @alecxe mentioned it should return all the elements present in the `DOM`

Comment: I tried getting the HTML source code and then used JSOUP to get the element based on the XPATH. My question is, xpath will be applied on the html source or only visible elements in selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's right. I also tried to made reference to elements that weren't in my page (because they were invisible) but I couldn't do that. If the elements are visible in the page you will have access to them.

I recommend you that, if this elements would be visible in some moment, for example, clicking a button, you will have to automatize all the proccess with Selenium and then made reference to them with Xpath, JQuery or whatever you want.

I expect it solves your doubts.